# Change JOptionPane and JFrame titlebar font

Tags: java, swing, fonts, joptionpane, substance

I have to specify the `Jframe` and `JOptionPane` elements' title bar to a Cambodian(unicode) text data.
The default font(dialog) doesn't render the text correctly, and I want to override the default font to something else.
Please give a hand, how can I override it?
I tried the followings, none of them worked. (LaF: Substance 7.2.1)

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font()));
UIManager.put("TitledBorder.font", Main.get_ui_font());
UIManager.put("Frame.font", Main.get_ui_font());
```

I tested above with both `Font` and `FontUIResource`, no difference!
The following code throws an internal substance api exception, it's about `nullpointerexception`, but with full stack, I cannot see any stack trace of my code, so weird, maybe a bug.

```
SubstanceLookAndFeel.setFontPolicy(new FontPolicy() {public FontSet getFontSet(String arg0, UIDefaults arg1) {
                FontSet fs=new FontSet() {
                    public FontUIResource getWindowTitleFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font());}
                    public FontUIResource getTitleFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font());}
                    public FontUIResource getSmallFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font().deriveFont(10.0F));}
                    public FontUIResource getMessageFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font());}
                    public FontUIResource getMenuFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font());}
                    public FontUIResource getControlFont() {return new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font());}
                };
                return fs;
            }
        });
```

Full Stack trace of above code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(SubstanceLookAn
dFeel.java:2150)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel.access$000(SubstanceLoo
kAndFeel.java:92)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel$3.run(SubstanceLookAndF
eel.java:2136)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.ja
va:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java
:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:11
6)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java
:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Could you post the code of the *Main.get_ui_font()* method?**

The task to draw the borders of `JFrames` and `JDialogs` windows is delegated to an external windowing system so I'm not so sure you can easly change them.

Furthermore:

- **Frame.font** is not a valid key.
- **TitledBorder.font** has nothing to do with the titles in `JFrames`, take a look to the documentation.
- **OptionPane.font** changes the font of the message inside the `OptionPane`

Anyway, for change a font with `UIManager.put()` you should give as parameters the key and a FontUIResource.
So, I'm not sure what your Main.get_ui_font() returns, but considereng the constructors of `FontUIResource` -- `FontUIResource(Font font)` and `FontUIResource(String name, int style, int size)` -- if returns `Font` than use 1; otherwise, if your method returns `FontUIResource`, use 2.

1. UIManager.put("key", new FontUIResource(Main.get_ui_font()));
2. UIManager.put("key", Main.get_ui_font());

Remember also that if you want to use a "non standard" font you should register it before to use it. For this use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(..)`

Comment: Bro, I register any font I want to work with, I also tested with both `Font` and `FontUIResource`, no any differences. I just tried many ways, and I would say this is so bad that we cannot change it.

Comment: Do you at least see any changes to the message of the OptionPane when you change the value of **OptionPane.font**? If yes, means that at least you are changing the font in a corret way. For change the windows' title you have no keys and i don't see any other workaround if not use `Jframe.undecorated(true)` and create a fake window decorator using internal pannels. Not really a easy and clean solution but I see no other way.

Comment: yes dude, I'm also disappointed. There is no any implicit way. But it loads the font from the OS default, maybe I can find a way to override it, don't know. thanks dude.